# How to set fixed entity relation in Doctrine 2

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I have abstract entity (App - base core):

```
namespace App\Bundles\AppBundle\Entity;

abstract class App extends ContainerAware implements AppInterface
{
// .....
}
```

and self entity:

```
namespace AppRus\Bundles\AppBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM,
    App\Bundles\AppBundle\Entity\App as BaseApp;

/**
 * App
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="apps")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="AppRus\Bundles\AppBundle\Entity\AppRepository")
 */
class App extends BaseApp
{
  // ....
}
```

and entity for control revisions:

```
namespace App\Bundles\AppBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * AppHistory
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="apps_history")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="App\Bundles\AppBundle\Entity\AppHistoryRepository")
 */
class AppHistory
{
    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="App\Bundles\AppBundle\Entity\App")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="app_apple_id", referencedColumnName="apple_id")
     */
    private $app;
}
```

I can't create relation AppHistory#app to App#apple_id

When I set entity to abstract class App, then doctrine create a new table "App"
When I set MappedSuperClass to abstract class App, I have error: http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/latest/reference/inheritance-mapping.html#mapped-superclasses

How can I create relation from AppHistory to abstract core App?

Comment: Can try replace target entity in doctrine event listener (loadClassMetadata), but in documentation - property $associationMappings is public and read-only

Answer (score 0):

My understanding is that that's not possible. I think you're doing things the wrong way, at least for Doctrine2.

First of all, from the Doctrine2 docs you mention:

> A mapped superclass is an abstract or concrete class that provides persistent entity state and mapping information for its subclasses, but which is not itself an entity.

You can't create a relation to something that's not an entity!

To solve your immediate problem (~version control~ in doctrine), check out [EntityAudit on Github](https://github.com/simplethings/EntityAudit) instead.

Comment: This is good entity audit, but i want create me logic generate history updated.

Comment: Editing targetEntity in association (loadClassMetadata) is work.

Comment: @ZhukV, I just don't understand what you're trying to do. Can you edit your question to explain more? Maybe link to the design pattern you're trying to implement.

Comment: i have a abstract core for saving application in my db. Next, each core extends from abstract core, and add configuration file for control abstract core. I want all core write in abstract core, and configure next cores only from configuration file.

Comment: To answer the question in your original question ("How i can create relation from AppHistory to abstreact core App?"), you can't. Relations must be from an entity to an entity. Each entity can still extend an abstract class